# Read inside .DAT file using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, backup

I have .DAT from SharePoint, to recover some of the data I need to read the .DAT file using C#.

Some of the options are

```
 StreamReader objInput = new StreamReader(filename, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
            string contents = objInput.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            string[] split = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(contents, "\\s+", RegexOptions.None);
            foreach (string s in split)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
```

or

```
//ObjectToSerialize objectToSerialize;
            //Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
            //BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            //objectToSerialize = (ObjectToSerialize)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
            //stream.Close();

.../
```

The problem is the DAT file may contain XMl files, Doc files, or PPT or others. I just want list all the data and files inside the .DAT file.

Is there is any way I can do this is C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can read .dat file using c#, but it depends on the structure of data how you have inside the .dat file

take a look at this link

[How-read-data-from-DAT-file-using-C](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/113857/How-read-data-from-DAT-file-using-C)

[how-can-i-read-data-from-dat-files](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10254433/how-can-i-read-data-from-dat-files.aspx)